# Javascript - How to obtain JSON Root Children Key by ignore its Parent Key dynamically?

Tags: javascript, json, object, foreach

**Code:**

```
const jsonFile = require("data.json")

// Get the KEY of the JSON but not the Data (failed to get Root Children Key, only get the Parent Key)
var getKey = Object.keys(jsonFile);

// Declared for do matching purpose
var matchData = "country"; 

// using for each loop and try to get all the key to do matching
for(var count in getKey){

    // get the key and do matching
    if(getkey[count]==matchData){
        //Do Something  
    }

}
```

**JSON File**

```
{
 "class" : {
   "id" : "abc123456",
   "name" : "Programming Class"
 },
 "address" : {    
   "postcode" : "30100",
   "city" : "IPOH",
   "state" : "PERAK",
   "country" : "MALAYSIA"
 }
}
```

I trying to get JSON Root Children Key by ignore its Parent Key dynamically.

For this example, I using `for each loop` and try to loop through the JSON file and get all its key, however I only able to get the **Parent Key** of `class` and `address`,

**My Desire Output:**

what I want is to get all the **Children Key** of `class` and `address` which are `id, name, postcode, city, state, country` in the `for each loop` and use them to do matching with the `matchData` I have declared.

How to archieve that?

**Note: (Please refer to JSON Below)**

1. I will always wanted to get the **root Children Key**, for example the JSON file below. I will wanted to get `code, number, first, last, postcode, city, state, country` and use them to do matching.
2. I am **NOT** trying to get the **Data** such as `abc, 123456, Programming, Class, 30100, IPOH, PERAK, MALAYSIA` but I wanted to get is the **Key**, `code, number, first, last, postcode, city, state, country`.

**Example JSON for my Note**

```
{
    "class": {
        "id": {
            "code": "abc",
            "number": "123456"
        },
        "name": {
            "first": "Programming",
            "last": "Class"
        },
    },
    "address": {
        "postcode": "30100",
        "city": "IPOH",
        "state": "PERAK",
        "country": "MALAYSIA"
    }
}
```

Comment: `jsonFile.address.country` should be country.

Comment: I'm sorry if my explanation isn't clear, I just wanted to get the key, I do not want to get any of the data of the key.

Comment: What's wrong with `Object.keys(jsonFile.class).concat(Object.keys(jsonFile.address))`?

Comment: I don't quite get your meaning @fubar can you clarify your suggestion? Thank you

Comment: If you just want to get the keys for the objects `class` and `address` in your JSON file, you can use the snippet above. Or I may have misunderstood your requirements, so please clarify your question.

Comment: almost there @fubar , by using `Object.keys(jsonFile.class).concat(Object.keys(jsonFile.address))` i can get all its root key, however, is it possible to get it dynamically? which mean if there is another JSON with lower level root, it can auto detect the root Key and get them instead of hardcode specify which level of root Key to get? for further clarification on my requirement, please refer to the Note i added.

Comment: Re-reading your question, it sounds like you want to recursively parse the JSON to pull out all the object keys. Is that correct? Will there be duplicates? Do you need the duplicates, or only unique keys?

Comment: yes @fubar , you are correct. If including duplicates mean taking all the Root Object Key that have been declared in the JSON file, then Yes. It would be helpful, if you willing to show me the solution for both including duplicate and excluding the duplicate one, so I can take both of them as reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automatically find the nested properties of the root objects using the following:

```js
var json = {
    "class": {
        "id": {
            "code": "abc",
            "number": "123456"
        },
        "name": {
            "first": "Programming",
            "last": "Class",
            "code": "234567"
        },
    },
    "address": {
        "postcode": "30100",
        "city": "IPOH",
        "state": "PERAK",
        "country": "MALAYSIA"
    }
};

function parseKeys(keys, obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (keys, key) {
    if (typeof obj[key] !== 'object') {
      return keys.concat(key);
    }
    
    return parseKeys(keys, obj[key]);
  }, keys);
}

// Keys with duplicates
var duplicateKeys = parseKeys([], json);

// Remove duplicates
var uniqueKeys = Array.from(new Set(duplicateKeys));

console.log(duplicateKeys, uniqueKeys);
```

Comment: sir, it is possible to have it return both Key and its Data in formatted JSON? which mean return something like this. {"code": "abc", "number": "123456", ...}

Comment: Yes, it is. Why don't you have a go, and post a question when you get stuck?

Comment: do you mean, I have to post another question for this Requirement?

Comment: I think you could figure it out from my previous answer. But if not, I think a new post would be a good idea, as you're now asking a different question.

Comment: Noted, I would try it out 1st, anywhere, thanks for your suggest solution.

Comment: I have changed my answer to give result in such a format